# Line with xml not showing up in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, view

So I am trying to draw a straight line in my layout.Here is my code

```
<View
   android:layout_width="5dp"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="#FF0000FF"
   android:layout_marginStart="20dp"/>
```

It works with a horizontal line but nothing shows up when it's a vertical line. Any help would be great!

Comment: Your snippet is perfectly working when wrapped inside a RelativeLayout. Post your full layout file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code

> For horizontal line

```
<View
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="2dp" //You can change height according to your need 
 android:background="#000000" // For transparency you can use #80000000(where 80 denote the alpha value)
 />
```

> For Vertical line

```
<View
 android:layout_width="2dp" //You can change width according to your need 
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 android:background="#000000" 
 />
```